# How to pass a color prop in React Native

Tags: react-native, colors, react-props

I would like to pass color prop to native sdk UI. I was trying to pass it in `style` prop but it did not help. Does anyone know, how to pass color on the native side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's strange that you have a problem with passing staff through flat props and styles object as it should be handled out of the box.

#### Simple case

The only thing that you need to do is mark the property with color type, on IOS.

```objectivec
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(myMagicColorProp, UIColor)
```

On Android colors are just simply integers so you should just simply use Integer

```kotlin
@ReactProp(name = "myMagicColor")
fun setColor(view: View, color: Int?) {
    // ...
}
```

#### Complex case

If you are trying to pass color in some nested structure e.g.

```js
<MyComponent data={{ magicColor: "red"}} />
```

You have to handle parsing color on your own.
Thankfully facebook gave us some tools for that.

First of all, you have to normalize the color on the JS side

```js
import { processColor } from 'react-native'


<MyComponent data={{ magicColor: processColor("red") }} />
```

Next on IOS you have to use `RCTConvert` to get `UIColor`

```swift
    @objc func setData(_ data: NSDictionary) {
        let color = RCTConvert.uiColor(data["magicColor"])
        /// ...
    }
```

On Android you don't have to do anything more than just simply use `getInt`

```kotlin
  @ReactProp(name = "data")
  fun setData(view: View, data: ReadableMap?) {
      view.setBackgroundColor(data.getInt("color"))
      /// ...
  }
```

Comment: Are there any documentations around the processColor method?